# Trocar cor do "button" ao clicar nele ou ao validar preenchimento texto

Tags: android

Olá galera estou tendo dificuldade em fazer com que o botão troque de cor quando os campos `EditText`s estiverem preenchidos e voltar a cor inicial quando os campos estivem vazios e também trocar de cor quando pressionado.

Trecho de código presente no `onCreate`:

```
senha.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!validar(matricula.getText().toString(), senha.getText().toString())){
            //btn_Entrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c9c9c9"));
            btn_Entrar.setClickable(false);
        }else if(!matricula.getText().toString().equals("")){
            btn_Entrar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2D89db"));
            btn_Entrar.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {}
});
```

Propriedade no XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_edit_text"
```

shape_edit_text:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_buttonlogin_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_buttonlogin_normal"/>
</selector>
```

shape_buttonlogin_pressed:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

shape_buttonlogin_normal:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#c9c9c9" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quando você usa no XML o atributo `background` esta dando um `StateListDrawable` como `background` do `Button`. Já quando usa `Button.setBackgroundColor` está sobrescrevendo o background com um `ColorDrawable` e com isso perde o comportamento de estado para uma cor fixa, causando o problema.

Logo como solução usando o `State List Drawable` que já definiu para seu botão, podemos adicionar o estado `state_enabled` para atingir o objetivo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Pressionado e Habilitado -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Habilitado e não pressionado -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#2D89db" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Desabilitado -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#c9c9c9" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Simplificando sua lógica de verificação, ficaria:

```
senha.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(!validar(matricula.getText().toString(), senha.getText().toString())){
            btn_Entrar.setEnabled(false);
        } else if(!matricula.getText().toString().equals("")){
            btn_Entrar.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {}
});
```